# VBS - Transfer oldest file every 2 minutes

Tags: vbscript

I found some similar threads but they didn't solve the full problem i'm having, first, i'm a complete amatour when it comes to VBS, so i'm sorry if this is a simple problem.

I need to build a vbscript that transfers the oldest file from folder A to B every 2 minutes, this is what i come up with:

```
Dim colFiles 
Dim strStartFolder 
Dim strDestinationfolder 
Dim oOldestFile 
Dim oFile 
Dim oFSO 
strStartFolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\a\" 
strDestinationfolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\b\" 
I=0    
Do While I=0
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set colFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files 
If colFiles.Count <= 1 Then 
WScript.Quit 
End If 
For Each oFile In colFiles 
   If Not IsObject(oOldestFile) Then 
       Set oOldestFile = oFile 
   Else 
       If oFile.DateLastModified < oOldestFile.DateLastModified Then 
           Set oOldestFile = oFile 
       End If 
   End If 
Next 
Do While i=0
oOldestFile.Move strDestinationfolder & "\" & oOldestFile.Name 
Wscript.Sleep (2000)
Loop
```

At the moment, the vbscript only tranfer the oldest file one time.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Thank you !

EDIT:
after the suggestions made by Hackoo and GJKH, the script looks like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim colFiles 
Dim strStartFolder 
Dim strDestinationfolder 
Dim oOldestFile 
Dim oFile 
Dim oFSO 
strStartFolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\a\" 
strDestinationfolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\b\"  
Do
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set colFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files 
Wscript.echo colFiles.Count 


    For Each oFile In colFiles 
        If Not IsObject(oOldestFile) Then 
            Set oOldestFile = oFile 
        Else 
            If oFile.DateLastModified < oOldestFile.DateLastModified Then 
                Set oOldestFile = oFile 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next 
    oOldestFile.Move strDestinationfolder & "\" & oOldestFile.Name
   ' Pause 1 ' sleep for 2 minutes
 Set oFSO = nothing
 Set colFiles = nothing 
Loop
'****************************************************************
Sub Pause(min)
    wscript.sleep(min * 60 * 1000)
End Sub
'****************************************************************
```

He transfer the first file and than loops ( activated ECHO ) but he does not transfer any more files after the first one, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I know more about vb.net than vbs but a couple of things strike me as odd that may be causing problems here...

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set colFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files
```

I would destroy these and recreate them each time it loops, in vb.net you would just set `oFSO = nothing` and `colFiles = nothing`, I'm sure the syntax is similar in vbscript.

```
If colFiles.Count <= 1 Then 
WScript.Quit
```

I take it there is more than one file in the folder after you move the oldest one - because if not then script exits here.

```
Wscript.Sleep (2000)
```

This method parameter is in milliseconds, if you want to update every 2 minutes this will need to be `Wscript.Sleep(120000)`, setting it to 2000 would be every 2 seconds.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help!, i removed the quit command on <=1 and changed the sleep command, also i added the oFSO = nothing and colFiles = nothing on the script.   The script runs perfect and loops fine, but it only transfer one file, after that the scrit only loops again and again without moving anything, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim colFiles 
Dim strStartFolder 
Dim strDestinationfolder 
Dim oOldestFile 
Dim oFile 
Dim oFSO 
strStartFolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\a\" 
strDestinationfolder = "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\b\"  
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set colFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files 
'Wscript.echo colFiles.Count
Do 
    'Wscript.echo colFiles.Count
    If colFiles.Count <= 1 Then 
    'Wscript.echo colFiles.Count
    WScript.Quit 
    End If 

    For Each oFile In colFiles 
        If Not IsObject(oOldestFile) Then 
            Set oOldestFile = oFile 
        Else 
            If oFile.DateLastModified < oOldestFile.DateLastModified Then 
                Set oOldestFile = oFile 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next 
    oOldestFile.Move strDestinationfolder & "\" & oOldestFile.Name 
    Pause 2 ' sleep for 2 minutes
Loop
'****************************************************************
Sub Pause(min)
    wscript.sleep(min * 60 * 1000)
End Sub
'****************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi, i thanks a lot for your help, the code is looping but not sending the files to the folder after the frist one ( i activated the ECHOs to see if the loop was working), also, i tried to remove the files coint <= 1 to see if that was the problem, but got the same result, any ideas ?

Comment: @LucasSchoenherr Can you explain more your aim and why you need to do it like that ?